# Z/OS Cobol 6.3 copy: how to include only a chunk?

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos, copybook

I need this information: I have a Cobol 6.3 program “PROGRAM1” that includes a copy statement `COPY1`. `COPY1` contains only data definition, it can be included in WORKING STORAGE or LINKAGE SECTION. I need to tailor the copy in the inclusion process. I need to include only the statement between two eye-catchers. It doesn’t matter the content of the eye-catcher, but it must be a comment, because `COPY1` is included In a lot of other COBOL programs, that must include the copy as is without significant modification.

Below an example:

PROGRAM1:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. PROGRAM1.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
DATA DIVISION.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    COPY COPY1 from eye-catcher 1 to eye-catcher 2**.

    ... Rest of program data definition ...

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    

    ... Rest of program logic ...

    STOP RUN.
```

** This isn’t a valid COBOL statement. It’s only for clarity.

COPY1:

```
01  AREA1 PIC X (10).

...eye-catcher 1...

01  AREA2 PIC X (10).

...eye-catcher 2...

01  AREA3 PIC X (10).

I need to include only :

01  AREA2 PIC X (10).
```

I've searched but found nothing. any idea?

Comment: You could create a copybook for the part of the copybook you want and use a nested copy in the original copybook source. That way you can imbed the part you want and it will still be included in the original copybook

Comment: *See*, [Conditional compilation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=directives-conditional-compilation) for an understanding of the directives available for doing this,

Comment: The option Rick provided is the one that matches most the request but will often be seen as "not COBOL", the option from Bruce is the "common way to go".

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I would like to add one piece of information for clarity: the copy and most of the programs that contain it are the property of a supplier and cannot be altered. A proprietary program contains this copy and the purpose of my request was precisely to have Cobol directives that could edit the copy so that it could be included partly in "WORKING STORAGE" and partly in "LINKAGE SECTION".  So I don't want to duplicate the copy and risk future misalignments, nor can I modify it.

Comment: I have also opened a case with IBM support and I am waiting for a response (I will publish it if it is conclusive). In the end, if there are no viable solutions, I will ask the supplier for a change like the one Bruce suggested.
I'm also trying to figure out if I can apply Rick's suggestion in some way.

Comment: I don't see the problem with including the whole copy book even though you don't use it all. Surely a few K of unused storage is not going to be a problem on modern hardware, and, an optimising compiler with probably drop the storage anyway. The other simpler solution would be to just COPY the bits of the orifginal copy book you want.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment basically if the Copybook

```
     01  First-part-of-copybook.
         ...
     01 Bit-i-want.
        ...
     01 The-Rest.
        ...
```

You create a new copybook called  say   myCopy

```
     01 Bit-i-want.
        ...
```

and the original copybook becomes

```
     01  First-part-of-copybook.
         ...
     copy bycopy.
     01 The-Rest.
        ...
```

and you would use bycopy in your program

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's third part software and I can't modify.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to modify COPY1 as @BruceMartin suggests, try...

```
COPY COPY1 REPLACING 
  ==01  AREA1 PIC X (10).== BY ====
  ==01  AREA3 PIC X (10).== BY ====
.
```

Comment: Unfortunately the copy contains a lot of other data definition  and it can changes in redefines. Anyway thanks a lot for your time.